# Spritekit node jitters while moving.... why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

Im trying to make a node move using SKAction but whenever I add the node and move it, it begins to jitter up and down along the y axis like crazy!

Any ideas?

I've tried using MoveToY, MoveTo, etc.. and no luck not sure what is causing the jitter..

Thanks..

```
-(void)addEnemy{
    enemy = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"enemy"];
    enemy.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(40, 40)];
    enemy.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
    enemy.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
    enemy.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = enemyHitCatagory;
    enemy.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = bulletHitCatagory;
    enemy.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = bulletHitCatagory;

    enemy.position = CGPointMake(random() % 300, CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame));
    enemy.size = CGSizeMake(40, 40);
    enemy.zPosition = 5;
    SKAction *attack = [SKAction moveTo:(CGPointMake(20, 300)) duration:(3)];
    [enemy runAction:[SKAction repeatAction:attack count:1]];


    [self addChild:enemy];

}
```

Comment: If I make enemy.physicsBody.dynamic = NO then it doesn't jitter but I have no collision detection...

Comment: Have you tried adding `enemy.physicsBody.restitution = 0`? And setting the same for whatever physics body it is hitting? Sounds to me like your enemy is just bouncing off a physics body. By default a physics body will have a restitution of 0.2.

Comment: Awesome!! that seems to have fixed it! thanks!! @pasta12

Comment: Great! I'll leave it as an answer for you to accept :)

Comment: dynamic body + move action = not a good idea. Consider that physics is supposed to control position and rotation properties of the node if you want the node to behave like a physics object. Even though the suggested workaround works for this particular situation, you'll likely run into even more issues going forward.

Comment: how would you suggest moving the nodes? @LearnCocos2D ?

Comment: applyForce and applyImpulse or change the body's velocity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the physics bodies are colliding. By default, an `SKPhysicsBody` has a `restitution` of `0.2`, making it a little bouncy. Setting `enemy.physicsBody.restitution = 0` and doing the same for the physics body your enemy is colliding with should resolve the jitter you're seeing.